# Django edit_post view not prepopulating form fields with existing data

Tags: django

I'm developing a Django blog application and I have a view to edit a post. However, when I click the Edit button, the form fields do not appear prepopulated with the existing data.

Here's my `edit_post` view code:

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("main_page")
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)

    context_dict = {
        "form": form,
        "post": post,
    }

    return render(request, "blog/edit_post.html", context_dict)
```

all_posts.html -> button that redirects to the Edit Post page.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit_post' post.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary me-2 btn-sm">Edit</button>
</form>
```

edit_post.html: part of the code where the form is.

```
<form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.media }}
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Title</label>
                    {{ form.title }}
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="{{ form.summary.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Summary</label>
                    {{ form.summary }}
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="{{ form.image_url.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Image URL</label>
                    {{ form.image_url }}
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="{{ form.body.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Body</label>
                    {{ form.body }}
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="{{ form.tags.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Tags</label>
                    {{ form.tags }}
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Post</button>
            </form>
```

I have verified that the PostForm is correctly configured with the required fields from the Post model. I also tried using the `@never_cache` decorator, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I'm not sure why the form fields are not prepopulated with the existing data after submitting the form. It only works when I manually reload the page.

Any suggestions or insights on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But after submitting the form successfully your code is redirecting to the main page. I assume there are no post form fields that should be populated. For me it is unclear at what stage the form fields keep being unpopulated while you expect them to be populated.

Comment: two questions? 1.  why you are sending post object separately to html page. 2. is your post object is null in get call.

Comment: @Tarquinius I am not sure I understand, but my idea is to when I click the "Edit" button I get redirected to the edit page and ideally the form fields are prepopulated with the existing data. After doing the changes, it gets redirected to the main page where all the posts are displayed.

Comment: @VinayVishwakarma I am not sure I understand the questions. I'll add more information to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, **the problem is the button** which brings the user to the post-edit-view!

You only want to issue a POST request when you want to send data with the request. **But** your button strangely is also sending a POST request. You have to change that. This can be just a normal link like this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'edit_post' post.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary me-2 btn-sm">
  Edit
</a>
```

Just because you are passing a parameter to the url does not mean that this has to be a POST request!

What is happening in your case: Your post-edit-view divides its logic into POST and GET requests. Usually you expect the GET part of the view being triggered when a user "goes" to the edit-view. Then the form would be populated correctly via `PostForm(instance=post)`. In your case you access the view already with a POST request, so the POST arm of the view gets triggered. Here you don't send any data with the request, so this `PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)` populates the form with empty data.

Answer (score 1):

Try these two things to solve the issue.

Check this code, your post object should be not null.

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
```

Second remove post object from context, it's not required.

```
context_dict = {
            "form": form,
            }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but nothing changed. The form still appears without the fields populated.

I was expecting that when I first click the "Edit" button it should do a GET request, not a POST request. Right?

When I first click the "Edit" button, this is the what I receive:
`[28/Jun/2023 06:33:05] "POST /edit_post/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 7551`

If I manually reload the page:
`[28/Jun/2023 06:33:09] "GET /edit_post/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 10242`